# Inserting an image into a Rich Text File in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image, rtf

I am attempting to insert an image into a rich text file. I have read some of the answers already, but I'm not getting it quite right. The code I am using is as follows:

```
            string[] imgfiles = Directory.GetFiles(dirin, "*.png");
            foreach (string imageFileName in imgfiles)
            {
                var someImage = Image.FromFile(imageFileName);
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                someImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] imgbytedata = memStream.ToArray();
                memStream.Close();
                memStream.Dispose();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < imgbytedata.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(imgbytedata[i]);
                }
                var imgstr = "{" + string.Format("\\pict\\pngblip\\picw{0}\\pich{1}\\picwgoal{0}\\pichgoal{1}\\bin binary {2}", someImage.Width, someImage.Height, sb.ToString()) + "}";
                sb = null;

                rtb.AppendText(imgstr);
            }
```

Comment: Probably should mention what is going wrong, i.e. are you getting some Exception or error message?

Comment: Did you see the update to my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are building your string from the byte array, you are appending the string version of your byte data, i.e. "76","127","90", etc.

One major problem (I don't know if this is your actual problem) is that when you attempt to read it, the reader has no idea how to extract bytes from it. Take this example...

```
var c = new StringBuilder();
c.Append(6);
c.Append(64);
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
```

OUTPUT:

```
"664"
```

Solution: Convert your byte array into a base64String with `Convert.ToBase64String` and store that in the file.

Like so....

```
var c = Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[] {6, 64});
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (var entry in Convert.FromBase64String(c))
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

OUTPUT

```
"BkA="

6
64
```

---

Another potential problem: I've heard tell that using `string.Format` with exceptionally large strings can cause problems. I can fathom a case in which you generate memory exceptions with large image files.

Solution: Don't use `string.Format`. Either append your headers to the `StringBuilder` first OR write the header and image data in two separate actions.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't separating the byte values in any way.  For example, suppose your image only had the four bytes 16, 23, 240 and 1 then you would append "16232401" to the string, which is plainly wrong.  I don't know what RTF expects, but you need separators or two-digit hex values or base64 or somesuch.

**Update**

RTF uses unseparated two-digit hex values with a CR/LF every 128 characters (or 64 bytes).  Something like this should do the trick:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // TODO: Append image headers here.
    // Then append image data:
    for (int i = 0; i != imgbytedata.Length; ++i)
    {
        if ((i % 64) == 0)
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", imgbytedata[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the asker wants to embed the image in the RTF.

I think this will solve your problem. Replace your for loop with this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < imgbytedata.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 64 == 0)
          sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(imgbytedata[i].ToString("X"));
}
```